# jQuery Alert Dialogs

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new on jquery and i was looking for something that could replace the confirm dialog. I found jQuery Alert Dialogs at http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/#demo
but jConfirm do not return the same values as confirm(). 
Is possible to write a function to get the same confirm() value?
It's about the meaning of callback function that I admit is not so clear for me :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jConfirm will never "return" anything because it's "event driven".

jConfirm waits until the user has made a decision and then it will call the callback function which will handle the answer. **But** jConfirm will not block the code execution flow like the standard `confirm(...)` does.

So if your previous code looks like this:

```
// ask for a decision
var answer = confirm("Leave website?"); // the whole script stops until the user has made a decision!

// process answer
if (answer){
    alert("Bye bye!"); // the script waits here until the user has clicked "ok"
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
else{
    alert("Thanks for sticking around!"); // the script waits here until the user has clicked "ok"
}
```

it should look like this in jQuery:

```
// previous code

// show confirm dialog but the script will not wait, the script execution goes forward

jConfirm('Leave website?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(answer) {

    // this is the callback function of the jConfirm dialog we made
    // we arrive here when the user has made a decision

    // the answer is true, he wants to leave
    if (answer){

      // show a jAlert box
      jAlert("Bye Bye!", "Some Title", function() {

        // this is the callback function of the jAlert box
        // we arrive here when the user has clicked "ok"

        // send him to google
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
      });

    }
    else{
      // show a jAlert box without any callback
        jAlert("Thanks for sticking around!", "Some Title");
    }

});

// the code that follows here will be immediately executed
// because unlike confirm(), jConfirm() will not block
// the code execution flow
```

And for illustration:

**The standard JavaScript confirm() execution flow**

```
  |
  |
  |
  \/
  confirm() waits for an answer... 
  no further code will be executed
  until the user has made a decision
  |
  |
  \/
  handle the user's answer
  |
  |
  \/
  further code 
  execution
```

**The jConfirm execution flow**

```
  |
  |
  \/ -------> jConfirm Dialog  
  |                 |
  |                 |
  |                 \/
  |             Callback function
  |             when the user has made
  |             a decision. 
  |             (handle the answer here)
  |                  
  |
  \/
 further code
 execution
```

Comment: I have another question related to jConfirm. It seems that if you call twice the function jConfirm only the last dialog is returned. Is a bug of jConfirm or dipend on the callback ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) from jQuery UI.  It's what I use.

You can make the buttons whatever you want and handle them like so:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({

    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

        Ok: function() {

            // Do whatever you want to do when the user clicks Ok

            // Lastly, close the dialog
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },
        Cancel: function() {

            // Do whatever you want to do when the user clicks Cancel

            // Lastly, close the dialog 
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `confirm()` function is a synchronous call (i.e. it returns only when the user has clicked a button). jQuery-type dialogs are asynchronous (one call to open it, and a callback with the result). So you have to use a callback function and write your code differently. It's not possible to have a jquery-type dialog running in a synchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the jconfirm in another function then wait for the response something like:

```
function Confirm(){
var response;
jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    response = r;
});
return response
}
```

now you can use `if(Confirm()){alert('Has been confirmed');}`

Comment: Seems that the alert is never called and the reason is in the aswer of @sled

Answer (score 0):

Please see the reusable code below. 
Please remember that , Jquery alert won't wait for the user action. The statement after showAlert() will be executed immediately.

```
/** dialogUtils.js  start */
var iconStyle = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>';
var messageStyleStart = '<span align="center" style="font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;font-size:9.3pt;">';
var messageStyleEnd = '</span>';
var alertDialogHeight =190;
var alertDialogWidth =460;
var fieldToFocus;
var $alertDialog;

/**
shows the alert box - if the title is passed display that otherwise shows 
the default title
message - message to display on the alert box
title - title of the box
fieldIdtoFocus - if you need to give the focus to any field after showing the alert (id of the field)
height
width

*/
function showAlert(message,title,fieldIdtoFocus,height,width)
{
    $alertDialog.html(iconStyle + messageStyleStart +message + messageStyleEnd);
    if(title =='undefined'|| null ==title ||''==title)
        $alertDialog.dialog( "option", "title", alertHeader );
    else
        $alertDialog.dialog( "option", "title", title );
    // check for the field focus value, if the value passed use it, otherwise reset it.
    if(fieldIdtoFocus == 'undefined' || null == fieldIdtoFocus || ''== fieldIdtoFocus)
        fieldToFocus = null;
    else
        fieldToFocus = fieldIdtoFocus;
    // check if got height
    if(height == 'undefined' || null == height || ''== height)
        $alertDialog.dialog( "option", "height", alertDialogHeight);
    else
        $alertDialog.dialog( "option", "height", height);
    //check if got width
    if(width == 'undefined' || null == width || ''== width)
        $alertDialog.dialog( "option", "width", alertDialogWidth);
    else
        $alertDialog.dialog( "option", "width", width);

    // open the alert dialog box    
    $alertDialog.dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
//jquery alert box - the general alert box
    $alertDialog = $('<div  style="vertical-align:middle;"></div>')
        .html('This Message will be replaced!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: 'top',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    if(null != fieldToFocus){
                        if($('#'+fieldToFocus).is(':visible')) // if it is visble then only show
                            $('#'+fieldToFocus).focus();
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});

/** dialogUtils.js  end */

// call the function from anywhere in your code after including the dialogUtils.js  above */

showAlert("Please enter your phone number",'Alert!','phoneNumber');
```